# How can I resolve axios post request that shows object object?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am posting form data including an image upload and am getting most of the data to display in the back ends console but for the image I am getting Object object and I can't figure out why? Any Ideas?
here is the front end

```
 images.forEach((i) => {
            data.append('images', images)    
        })

//   axios post requst to back ed happens here 

          const form = document.querySelector("form");
  if (form) {
    form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const data = new FormData(form);
      axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/user", data, {
          headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    });
  }
```

and the back using node js

```
const fileupload = require("express-fileupload");
app.use(fileupload());
app.post('/api/v1/user',v1,(req,res) =>{

    let images = req.files.images;

  console.log (images, res);

  res.send(`
    
    Your image  is: ${images}

  `);
});
```

Comment: I think data.append('images', images) should be data.append('images', images[i]).

Comment: tried it,it changed from object object to undefined.

Comment: Please share me the code where data is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
images.forEach((image) => {
        data.append('images', image)    
    })
```